# Explain how this reveals the number of roots in $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

If this takes place in a simple and smooth closed curve $\gamma$, that doesn't cross itself explain why for the polynomial, f(x),

$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx$ tells you the number of roots of $f(x)$ inside the loop.  What is the order of $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$?

Comment: please make sure I edited your problem correctly. Thanks

Comment: Probably should be $\frac{1}{2\pi}i$.

Comment: This must be related to the Cauchy integral... Did you forget to mention that f is a polynomial?

Comment: This is correct, although "the integral of" can be changed into the integral symbol. Thank you for helping edit this questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to look at it is that it is basically the [*Winding Number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) with the curve $C$ taken to be smooth, closed, and only completes one loop (I know, that's a very formal way of saying it). As Wikipedia says, it is a special case of the Cauchy integral formula. Proof of this is not terribly complicated, but somewhat involved. I won't repeat the proof of CIF here; you can find it many places online.

Essentially, the roots of $f(x)$ are the poles of $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$. A curve such as the boundary of a disc encircles each pole once. The Winding number counts the poles; hence, the number of zeros of $f(x)$.

---

Edit: In the same light as Jyrki's comments, and with respect to the OP's comment that the curve never crosses itself, then the curve always encircles the poles in the same direction. For instance, if you had poles at $\pm \frac12 i$, then the boundary of the unit disc encircles both poles once in the counterclockwise direction. But if you drew a figure 8 that looped CCW around $\frac12 i$, crossed itself at the origin, and looped CW around $-\frac12 i$, then the count cancels itself out: $+1$ for the loop around $\frac12 i$, and $-1$ for the backwards loop around $-\frac12 i$.

However, the curve could cross itself arbitrarily many times, as long as the loops don't encircle any poles.

Comment: +1 But it is worth noting that the residue of $f'(x)/f(x)$ at a zero is equal to the multiplicity of the said zero. Hence the integral will automatically get the correct multiplicity. Newcomers to the theory are also advised to always check that the path will go around the zero in a counterclockwise direction. This is included in the definition of the winding number.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well said!

Comment: What if it never crosses itself?

Comment: @Tom What if what never crosses itself? The curve? The curve is closed; $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$ by definition. I've added an edit to explain why/how "never crosses itself" is relevant.